# Is there a way to add shortcuts to open a particular folder in Save Dialogs and Finder Windows?

Tags: keyboard, finder

I know that when you're saving or opening a file <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> shoots you to the Desktop folder, and pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> whilst using finder shoots you to the desktop folder as well.

**Is there a way to create a custom shortcut to jump to your own choice of folder?** (e.g. <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> for your 'Work' folder).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, no.  What I've done is drag folders I access frequently to the Places section in the left side bar.  There is software to accomplish this though.  [Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/) does this, and more.

If you're in a save dialogue you can press <kbd>/</kbd> to get a file path dialogue, or press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to get a "Go to folder" dialogue.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give DFX a go; also good to know the / trick. I'll see if anyone else has any suggestions and come back and Correct Answer your answer.

Comment: Since DFX is $50NZ I might leave it for now, looks great though. I've put an alias to my work folder in the top level, and I'm going to try going /W <TAB> to get there quick. Not ideal, but looks like best built in option so far.

Answer (score 2):

Not a shortcut, but you can drag finder proxy icons (in the titlebar), folders and even files into open/save dialogues to jump to the folder (if you drag a file, the file name field will be prefilled with its file name).