# Custom finder shortcut keys

Tags: finder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to add shortcuts to open a particular folder in Save Dialogs and Finder Windows?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10344/is-there-a-way-to-add-shortcuts-to-open-a-particular-folder-in-save-dialogs-and)

Is it possible to set custom shortcut keys for finder, for example at the moment we have CMD+Shift+A to go to Applications, could finder be programmed to CMD+Shift+S for sites for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way to do this is by using a third party utility. You will need an app where you can assign an applescript to a shortcut. A few examples of these apps :

[FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/)

[Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/)

You would then create an Applescript/Bash script that will open that folder and assign the shortcut to run that script.

Comment: I like the look of FastScripts, cheers!